# Regex - Detect two or more consecutive symbols

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9A-Z]{1}([0-9A-Z_-]{0,38}[0-9A-Z]{1}){0,1}$
```

that validates that:

- String has between 3 and 42 characters
- Only letters, number, - or _ can be used
- First two position are letters
- Third character cannot be a symbol (_ or -)
- Last character cannot be a symbol (_ or -)

I need to update the regex to detect strings that have identical consecutive symbols (--, __, *- or -*):

- RR1_-1 (NOT VALID)
- RR1___1 (NOT VALID)
- RR1-1-1 (VALID)

I have ended with:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9A-Z]{1}([0-9A-Z_-]{0,38}(?!(--|__|-_|_-))[0-9A-Z]{1}){0,1}$
```

But it does not work. How can detect two consecutive symbols?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is forbidden?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the negative lookahead assertion right after the beginning of the string and not in the middle of the pattern. Afterwards, it should work assuming the rest of the pattern ist right.